# how to access components of system application protected with "signatureOrSystem" permission?

Tags: android

I want to access the components of system application(present in the source code - ICS) protected with "signatureOrSystem" permission, in other application(not present in source code). Is it possible? If yes then please provide some reference.

Answer (score 0):

You Can not choose protected applications with [signatureOrSystem](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) 
As per documentation system grants only to applications that are in the Android system image or that are signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission.

for accessing system application you need **same certificate**